# Jinja2 - How to loop a json list?

Tags: json, python-2.7, jinja2

How can I loop a json list with jinja2?

I have this json list,

```
[
    {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "user_id": 4,
        "address": null
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Heart",
        "user_id": 5,
        "address": null
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Dom",
        "last_name": "Robinsons",
        "user_id": 6,
        "address": null
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Pete",
        "last_name": "Hand",
        "user_id": 7,
        "address": null
    }
]
```

page.html,

```
<table>
   {% for user in users %}
   <tr><td>{{ user.first_name }}</td></tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Result,

```
<table>

   <tr><td></td></tr>

   <tr><td></td></tr>

   <tr><td></td></tr>

   <tr><td></td></tr>
   ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

your json list contains dictionaries; you need to access the dictionary elements differently than you would class members; try:

```
<tr><td>{{ user['first_name'] }}</td></tr>
```

this works for me (python 3.4 and python 2.7)

```
import json
from jinja2 import Template

json_str = '''[{"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith", "user_id": 4, 
    "address": null}, {"first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Heart",
    "user_id": 5, "address": null}, {"first_name": "Dom",
    "last_name": "Robinsons", "user_id": 6, "address": null},
    {"first_name": "Pete", "last_name": "Hand", "user_id": 7,
    "address": null}]'''

users = json.loads(json_str)

tmpl = Template('''
<table>
   {% for user in users %}
   <tr><td>{{ user['first_name'] }}</td></tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
''')

print(tmpl.render(users = users))
```

output:

```
<table>

   <tr><td>John</td></tr>

   <tr><td>Jane</td></tr>

   <tr><td>Dom</td></tr>

   <tr><td>Pete</td></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: `you json list contains dictionaries` - what is a dictionary made? I mean how to recognise a data / json contains dictionary.

Comment: a dictionary is a key, value collection. in python; `d = {key: value}`.

Comment: it is a json too, isn't? like this one - `{"key": "value"}` isn't a json?

Comment: yep, the json string `'{"key": "value"}'` translates to the python dictionary `{"key": "value"}`. that's what the `json` module does for you.

Comment: jinja2 can not parse json, no. it takes python objects of any form as arguments (a list of dictionaries in your case). but you have to convert the json string to that first. that's what the json module does for you (one visible conversion here is that hte json string `'null'` is mapped to the python `None`).

Comment: I see. what `json.loads` does is to convert the typical json to 'python json', doesn't?

Comment: well `json.loads` converts a string to python objects (as good as it can).

Answer (score 2):

simple json iteration in jinja2

```
<table>
   <tr>
       {% for key in users[0] %}
       <th>{{ key }}</th>
       {% endfor %}
   </tr>

   {% for user in users %}
   <tr>
       {% for key in user %}
       <td>{{ user[key] }}</td>
       {% endfor %}
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
```